# Having issues with MeteorRider/Phonegap/Cordova and Leaderboard example

Tags: cordova, meteor

I new am using Meteor and Cordova/Phonegap and seem to have run into an issue (hopefully it's simple to solve).

I am using:

Cordova 3.5.0-0.2.6
Meteor 0.8.3
I have installed:
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser
I also installed meteor-oauth-demo (https://github.com/AdamBrodzinski/meteor-oauth-demo) as my app needs it.

& got a copy of MeteorRider earlier today and followed (perhaps I missed something) the installation/config guide.

I am having issues just pointing to the leaderboard sample application (http://leaderboard.meteor.com/), all I see is:

[image: screenshot of iPhone emulator]

On a browser I see the full application:

[image: screenshot of desktop browser]

MeteorRider init is:

```
  document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
          // do whatever stuff on deviceready
          // ....

          // put all your phonegap specific initializer code here
          // ....

          // if testing phonegap api/plugin, you may want to disable MeteorRider
          //   in which case you can display your own HTML w/o Meteor
          // ....

          // ok - go ahead and initialize MeteorRider (go get some!)
          //MeteorRider.init("http://test.buzzy.buzz/");
          /*** for more control ***/
           var config = {
          meteorUrl: 'http://leaderboard.meteor.com/',
          currentPath: '',
          localStorage: true,
          // step 1) loading text
          doLoading: true,
          // step 2) AJAX request
          doRequest: true,
          // step 3) AJAX response (or cache) replacing DOM
          doReplace: true
        };
           MeteorRider.init(config);


      }, false);
```

The emulator log file has:

```
Aug  4 16:25:08 Adams-MacBook-Pro-2.local SimulatorBridge[53325] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installing app for existing placeholder LSApplicationProxy: io.cordova.hellocordova
Aug  4 16:25:08 Adams-MacBook-Pro-2.local SimulatorBridge[53325] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Not creating progress for LSApplicationProxy: io.cordova.hellocordova since it is not a placeholder.
Aug  4 16:25:08 Adams-MacBook-Pro-2.local installd[53332] <Notice>: 0xb0115000 handle_install_for_ls: Install of "/Users/adamginsburg/Documents/Development/cordova-info-app/platforms/ios/build/emulator/HelloCordova.app" requested by SimulatorBridge
Aug  4 16:25:08 Adams-MacBook-Pro-2.local installd[53332] <Notice>: 0xb0115000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Installing app io.cordova.hellocordova
Aug  4 16:25:08 Adams-MacBook-Pro-2.local installd[53332] <Notice>: 0xb0115000 install_application: Performing developer delta patch
Aug  4 16:25:08 Adams-MacBook-Pro-2.local installd[53332] <Notice>: 0xb0115000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Staging: 0.01s; Waiting: 0.00s; Installation: 0.01s; LS Sync: 0.00s; Overall: 0.02s
Aug  4 16:25:08 Adams-MacBook-Pro-2.local lsd[53341] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Updating identifier store
Aug  4 16:25:08 Adams-MacBook-Pro-2.local SpringBoard[60501] <Error>: libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:835: still-camera is static and will never generate a notification
Aug  4 16:25:08 Adams-MacBook-Pro-2.local SpringBoard[60501] <Error>: libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:835: stand-alone-contacts is static and will never generate a notification
Aug  4 16:25:08 Adams-MacBook-Pro-2.local backboardd[53326] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:io.cordova.hellocordova[0xe98]' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9
Aug  4 16:25:08 Adams-MacBook-Pro-2.local SpringBoard[60501] <Warning>: BKSWorkspace: Ignoring exit of io.cordova.hellocordova as it is pending activation, and will be relaunched.
Aug  4 16:25:08 Adams-MacBook-Pro-2.local SimulatorBridge[53325] <Warning>: Application launched after 0.00 seconds.
Aug  4 16:25:08 Adams-MacBook-Pro-2.local backboardd[53326] <Error>: HID: The 'Passive' connection 'HelloCordova' access to protected services is denied.
Aug  4 16:25:08 Adams-MacBook-Pro-2.local backboardd[53326] <Warning>: CoreAnimation: timed out fence b6a3
Aug  4 16:25:08 Adams-MacBook-Pro-2.local HelloCordova[61082] <Notice>: BUG in libdispatch: 13E28 - 866 - 0x2
Aug  4 16:25:08 Adams-MacBook-Pro-2.local HelloCordova[61082] <Notice>: BUG in libdispatch client: kevent[EVFILT_VNODE] add: "Bad file descriptor" - 0x9
Aug  4 16:25:08 Adams-MacBook-Pro-2.local HelloCordova[61082] <Warning>: Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
Aug  4 16:25:08 Adams-MacBook-Pro-2.local HelloCordova[61082] <Warning>: Unlimited access to network resources
Aug  4 16:25:08 Adams-MacBook-Pro-2.local HelloCordova[61082] <Warning>: 

Started backup to iCloud! Please be careful.
Your application might rejected by Apple if you store too much data.
For more information please read "iOS Data Storage Guidelines"
You could find it at the following address https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/ .
Aug  4 16:25:08 Adams-MacBook-Pro-2.local SpringBoard[60501] <Warning>: No transaction in -[SBWorkspace workspace:applicationActivated:]
Aug  4 16:25:08 Adams-MacBook-Pro-2.local HelloCordova[61082] <Warning>: Resetting plugins due to page load.
Aug  4 16:25:08 Adams-MacBook-Pro-2.local HelloCordova[61082] <Warning>: Finished load of: file:///Users/adamginsburg/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/7.1/Applications/C0C98109-404D-44B6-B34A-BBCEF78151F9/HelloCordova.app/www/index.html
```

I do see some errors there, but I am not 100% sure what they mean and which one is the key culprit?

BTW, I did successfully create the hello world example with my own simple app... however, I fell over on this example one as well as my own real app. I figured if I can work it out on this basic one, I could hopefully apply that solution  to me more complex app.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Everything that you posted looks right... 

do you have a github repo that I can poke around at?

are you testing this only from an emulator or also from a device?

are you only looking at the iOS platform?  Does it work from Android?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I jumped ship, as I think I need to use Cordova plugins and it seems that they may be troublesome based on some of your comments. I am using [meteor-cordova-loader](https://github.com/andrewreedy/meteor-cordova-loader) and it seems to be working so far. So will probably stick with this approach for now. Thanks again.

Comment: I think the "plugins problems" I had were not necessarily related to MeteorRider, but I'm also watching meteor-cordova-loader... once they figure out the problem with versions, I'll probably start recommending that approach.
https://github.com/andrewreedy/meteor-cordova-loader/issues/16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since posting this question there have been significant advances in the Meteor-Cordova/Phone gap integration. Therefore, question has become kinda redundant as from Meteor 0.9.3+ Phonegap/Cordova integration is handled out of the box and it works pretty well.

Documentation on the out of the box capability is on the wiki here https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Meteor-Cordova-Phonegap-integration

For those still working on a pre 0.9.3 release I did manage to get things working with the alternative approach https://github.com/andrewreedy/meteor-cordova-loader , however there were issues with various Oauth options... eg I got it working with Twitter & Facebook but got inconsistent behavior with Google.